# How to perform window.scrollTo operation in cdk/scrolling (Customized Scrollbar)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know we do window.scrollTo(50,0) in the default scroll bar. I'm using angular material `cdk/scrolling` to create a viewport scroller inside the main page.

But I don't know how to do the `window.scrollTo` options in the customized scroll view. (i.e) if I click some button, it should move.

Here we have the documentation to do it, I'm new to angular so using Interface/Type aliases are new to me.

Here is the documentation https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api

Answer (score 1):

`cdkScrollable` directive helps to do this action.

1. Add `cdkScrollable` directive in `app.component.html` or your own template

   `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport cdkScrollable>...</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`
2. Create a variable to view the child component in `app.component.ts` or your own class

   `@ViewChild(CdkScrollable) cdkScrollable: CdkScrollable;`
3. In a function, by using `scrollTo` method we can achieve it.

   `this.cdkScrollable.scrollTo({left: 3000});`

`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties are available.